# how to remove orphaned managed identity of app service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

Somehow I got a managed identity for which the main application has long been deleted. how to remove it? please help

I can either run the following command to find the MSI object (note the $appServiceName appService no longer exists)

```
PS C:\src\S\aspbuild-arm\azure\scripts> az ad sp list --display-name $appServiceName
[
  {
    "accountEnabled": "True",
    "addIns": [],
    "alternativeNames": [
      "isExplicit=False",
      "/subscriptions/99a0...645c6d1f/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/appservice-name"
    ],
    "appDisplayName": null,
    "appId": "d85bfd2d-2d93-4b13-864c-1321ac6c9ad1",
    "appOwnerTenantId": null,
    "appRoleAssignmentRequired": false,
    "appRoles": [],
    "applicationTemplateId": null,
    "deletionTimestamp": null,
    "displayName": "appservice-name",
    "errorUrl": null,
    "homepage": null,
    "informationalUrls": null,
    "keyCredentials": [
      {
        "additionalProperties": null,
        "customKeyIdentifier": "8173F9C433B4C0EFEE14E3FE5F2B9DB0C7D81898",
        "endDate": "2021-09-02T06:49:00+00:00",
        "keyId": "6ff17781-87f7-4b19-abda-a3066aafa5fc",
        "startDate": "2021-06-04T06:49:00+00:00",
        "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
        "usage": "Verify",
        "value": null
      }
    ],
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "notificationEmailAddresses": [],
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "objectId": "8f8c3360-fc2f-4a5e-a97a-f3b6fba6d972",
    "objectType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.ServicePrincipal",
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "preferredSingleSignOnMode": null,
    "preferredTokenSigningKeyEndDateTime": null,
    "preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint": null,
    "publisherName": null,
    "replyUrls": [],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "samlSingleSignOnSettings": null,
    "servicePrincipalNames": [
      "d85bfd2d-2d93-4b13-864c-1321ac6c9ad1",
      "https://identity.azure.net/ZoZNNul3HNZB6XiExPJTR2+ZNTIByGOiR23h9Nu81y0="
    ],
    "servicePrincipalType": "ManagedIdentity",
    "signInAudience": null,
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
  }
]
```

or I can search for the MSI under "Enterprise applications" blade and if I click on it and go to its properties, and try navigate to its app, i get "resource not found". screenshots attached.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Even if I try to delete from command line, I can't do it.
[image]

update: running az ad sp delete also gives error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". I have global admin and suspect its because its an MSI and supposed to be managed by Azure entirely
[image]

Comment: Oh my bad. I just thought you used a wrong cmd. We can't delete managed identity from AAD-side. We should manage it from Azure subscription side. Not sure why the azure service is deleted but managed identity remains. So in this case, it's recommended to contact Azure support to delete it for you.

Comment: Finally I had to open a support ticket with Microsoft, and they deleted it.

Comment: @AllenWu - It happened to me with a trial subscription with a VM in it (and hence managed idenity); and the trial expired.  Makes it hard to delete the no-longer-wanted AzureAD tennant.